# Что означает строчка implements OnClickListener?

Tags: android, java

Всем привет!

Начинаю помаленьку изчуать java и андройд. Дошел до событий. Чтобы отрабатывать клик по кнопке через активит, пишут

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener
```

В принципе немного понятно. Создается клаcc main, activity наследует от actionVarActivity.

А что такое **implements OnClickListener**?

Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это означает, что класс реализует интерфейс OnClickListener. В этом интерфейсе описан (но не реализован) какой-то метод, и этот класс обязан реализовать его (т.е. добавить тело).

Comment: О, теперь понятно! А я могу добавить несколько интерфейсов? Или только один интерфейс для одного класса?

Comment: Интерфейсов реализовать (implements) можно очень и очень много. Через запятую. А вот наследоваться (слово extends) можно только от одного класса.